# Arduino + Bluetooth + ROS : Error

Tags: ros, arduino, bluetooth, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Respected all,
My task is to get the orientation sensor data from the phone and send it to the ROS for further processing.

I have decided to implement this via the following procedure:
1: Android App
|
2: Bluetooth Shield
|
3: Arduino (retrieving real time orientation data from android app)
|
4: ROS (Rosserial)

I have implemented the first three steps and have retrieved the orientation data on arduino serial monitor on real time.

Now, when I am trying to use the serial_node.py (from the [ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_arduino/Tutorials/Hello%20World)), using the command:

```
rosrun rosserial_python serial_node.py _port:=/dev/ttyACM0 _baud:=9600
```

I am getting the following error!
[image: image description]

**This works well when I tried the conventional "Hello World" example of the rosserial. This means that the node files are working well.
Also, i have use the command "nh.getHardware()-> setBaud(9600);" to set the baud rate.**

Following is the code i am trying. (Please note that there can be manyy error in the code). I have edited the conventional "hello world" program and the arduino bluetooth code to get the orientation string

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h>;

#include <ros.h>
#include <std_msgs/String.h>

ros::NodeHandle nh;
std_msgs::String str_msg;
ros::Publisher chatter("chatter", &str_msg);


SoftwareSerial myBT (11, 10);
const int ledPin = 13;
String inCode = "";
boolean endCode = false;

void setup () {
  nh.getHardware()-> setBaud(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode (ledPin, OUTPUT);
  inCode.reserve (30);
  nh.initNode();
  nh.advertise(chatter);
}

void loop () {
  if (myBT.available ()) {
    char incomingChar = myBT.read ();
    if (incomingChar == ')') {
      endCode = true;
    } 
    else 
    {
      inCode  = (inCode + incomingChar);
    }
  }

  if (endCode) {
    int comma1 = inCode.indexOf (',');
    int comma2 = inCode.indexOf (',', comma1 + 1);
    String As = inCode.substring (0, comma1);
    String Ps = inCode.substring (comma1 + 1, comma2);
    String Rs = inCode.substring (comma2 + 1);

    Serial.print ("inCode =");
    Serial.print (inCode);
    Serial.print ("Azimuth =");
    Serial.print (As);
    Serial.print ("Pitch =");
    Serial.print (Ps);
    Serial.print ("Roll =");
    Serial.println (Rs);
    str_msg.data = 'As';
    chatter.publish( &str_msg );
    nh.spinOnce();
    delay(1000);

    int A = As.toInt ();
    int P = Ps.toInt ();
    int R = Rs.toInt ();

    inCode = "";
    endCode = false;
  }
}
```

Why am i getting such errors?
Kindly help.
Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264069/arduino-+-bluetooth-+-ros-:-error/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-06-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Have you tried using *rosserial_server* instead of *rosserial_python*? For me this solved a big part of the problem. Seems like *rosserial_python* cannot handle the connections most of the times so it's safer to use the *server* mode.

You can check http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial_server.

---

Originally posted by [thepirate16](https://answers.ros.org/users/26128/thepirate16/) with karma: 101 on 2017-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2017-06-26**:
Respected,
I have tried the same earlier.
But, no positive results!!!!